# How to reference Cognito UserPoolDomain alias target within CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

I want to create A record for Cognito UserPoolDomain alias target (Cognito auto-generated Cloudfront distribution) within CloudFormation template.

I didn't find in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpooldomain.html#aws-resource-cognito-userpooldomain-return-values) how to reference alias target of UserPoolDomain?

Should I create a Cloudfront distribution and then somehow pass it to Cognito?

This is snippet of my CloudFormation template and what I try to achieve:

```yaml
...
  AuthUserPoolDomain:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain
    Properties:
      UserPoolId: !Ref AuthUserPool
      Domain: auth.example.com
      CustomDomainConfig:
        CertificateArn: !Ref CertificateArn
  AuthRecordSets:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: example.com.
      RecordSets:
        - Name: auth.example.com
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            DNSName: ???
            EvaluateTargetHealth: false
            HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2 #  This is always the hosted zone ID when you create an alias record that routes traffic to a CloudFront distribution.
...
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround solution I've created a new CloudFormation template that accept Cognito target alias as a parameter (CognitoDistribution).

After Cognitio UserPoolDoman is created I run this to find distribution

```bash
aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool-domain --domain auth.example.com \
 | jq -r '.DomainDescription.CloudFrontDistribution'
```

and then I create DNS record with this template

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Add CNAME record for Cognito UserPoolDomain alias target (CloudFront distribution). 
  It is not part of same template as AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain because UserPoolDomain does not return distribution ref.
Parameters:
  HostedZoneName:
    Type: String
  UserPoolDomain:
    Type: String
  CognitoTargetAlias:
    Type: String
Resources:
  AuthRecordSets:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: !Sub "${HostedZoneName}."
      RecordSets:
        - Name: !Ref UserPoolDomain
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            DNSName: !Ref CognitoTargetAlias
            EvaluateTargetHealth: false
            #  This is always the hosted zone ID when you create an alias record that routes traffic to a CloudFront distribution.
            HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
```

not clean solution but at least I don't need to do it in console